# How can I attach YUI3 modules synchronously?

Tags: asynchronous, module, yui, loading

I want to attach YUI modules synchronously.

```
Given the YUI modules are already on the page
When I run: console.log YUI().use('base').Base
Then I get `undefined`
```

However,

```
When I run: YUI().use('base', (Y) -> console.log Y.Base)
Then I eventually get the Y.Base ctor function
```

It looks like loader is attaching async as it works fine using the callback method. IIRC the first method is supposed to work too though. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using YUI in a controlled environment like Node.js, then you should be able to use `useSync` configuration:

```
YUI({ useSync: true }).use('base').Base
```

But in a browser, or any other client runtime you should stick to the asynchronous nature of `Y.use` so loader can do its job of computing the proper list of modules to be attached based on the feature detections etc. Having the modules included manually in the pase is just not enough. Imagine the `scrollview-base` in IE, which requires an special module called `scrollview-base-ie`, unless you do detection when building the initial markup that includes that module only when running in IE, you will have a missing module. Again, stick to the asynchronous pattern when loading stuff.

Comment: This is a controlled environment. I think I understand the benefits to the asynch approach. None the less, I'd still like to get this done, but it doesn't appear to work. Is there something wrong with this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/uvrMp/3/

Answer (score 0):

YUI modules really want to be called through a Y object in a callback. If you know for sure that all the code you need is loaded on the page, you can attach them all synchronously with a use *. See https://github.com/evangoer/yui3-cookbook/blob/master/examples/loading/use_synchronous.html for an example.